# keep an old value on onchange event

Tags: javascript, file

Supposed I have a function for previewing image

```
previewImages: function()
{
   var preview = document.querySelector('#img_preview');
   let iFileLength = this.files.length;
   let oldValue = iFileLength;
   console.log(oldValue);
}

this.oTweetImg.addEventListener("change", oHome.previewImages);
```

The 3 here is where I selected the 3 files. right after that I close and then pick again another file and it resets the length to 1. The 1 here should be 4

[image]

How can I save the previous/old length of an inputted file. I tried to put it on a variable, however it still resets the length.

Im using `<input type="file" id="tweet_img" multiple/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let oldValue = iFileLength;` will be forgotten once the code exits `previewImages`. So the second time `previewImages` is called, there won't be another instance of `oldValue`. You will need to use [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (declare a variable outside the scope it's being used in, and manipulate that variable from that inner scope).

You can either store the latest length:

```
var lastSize = [];

var oHome = {
  previewImages: function() {
    var preview = document.querySelector('#img_preview');
    lastSize = this.files.length;
    console.log(lastSize);
  }
};

this.oTweetImg.addEventListener("change", oHome.previewImages);
```

Or you can store all the past lengths:

```
var sizeHistory = [];

var oHome = {
  previewImages: function() {
    var preview = document.querySelector('#img_preview');
    sizeHistory.push(this.files.length);
    console.log(sizeHistory);
    console.log(sizeHistory.reduce(function(sum, size){ return sum + size; }, 0));
  }
};

this.oTweetImg.addEventListener("change", oHome.previewImages);
```

Comment: for example sir i selected a 3 file and I console log it. The result is 3. after i close and select again a 1 file the console.log value should be 4

Comment: @Beginner If the same file is selected in both the first and the second selection, should the output still be 4, or should it be 3?

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following way through which you will get the how many total images have selected

```
var totalImage = 0; 
previewImages: function()
{
   var preview = document.querySelector('#img_preview');
   let iFileLength = this.files.length;
   totalImage = totalImage + iFileLength;

   console.log(totalImage); //4
}

this.oTweetImg.addEventListener("change", oHome.previewImages);
```